# If the Earth stopped spinning, which way would the wind and waves sweep?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy

I just started reading the book *what if?* by the brilliant Randall Munroe. One of the first questions is

> 'What would happen if the Earth and all terrestrial objects suddenly stopped spinning, but the atmosphere retained its velocity?'

He then excellently explains what would happen but I was confused by a particular line on page 4, where he talks about what would happen after the surface winds died down:

> 'wind sweeping over the oceans would churn up...The waves would sweep around the globe, **east to west**, and every **east-facing** shore would encounter the largest storm'

The sun rises in the East and sets in the West, so the Earth is rotating towards the East,
or counter-clockwise, if you're looking down at Earth from above the North Pole. If the Earth stopped rotating, then the atmosphere should continue to spin around the Earth counter-clockwise, **West to East** and not vice-versa, like the book says. Have I made a mistake? Is there some other factor that causes the  wind to go the other way?

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: This error appears in the original what-if.xkcd post .   However,  keep in mind that the original question stopped everything except the atmosphere.   Folks in other forums have  discussed what happens if you stop the crust but not the molten interior, or not the solid core, and so on.

Comment: Another thought: given the different ground-speed (of the air) with latitude, you'll probably create some seriously huge hurricanes and I'm not sure it's easy to say which way they'll propagate.

Comment: You can't have a hurricane with no Coriolis force...which is why we don't get them on the equator, even though other conditions are favorable.

Comment: @JEB  I see your point. So I guess unless there's significant difference in ground-effect drag on the atmosphere over different latitudes, that won't happen.